# Как считывать картинки в java se 1.6 1.7 ?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
ImageIcon sid = new ImageIcon(Puzzle.class.getResource("help.jpg"));
source = sid.getImage();
```

Почему-то выдает `NullPointerException` и на jre 1.6 и на jre 1.7 и в InteliJ Idea и в Eclipse Indigo, я уже прописывал и абсолютный путь к файлу и относительный и в разных проектах. помогите.

Answer (score 1):

Файл `help.jpg` если иное не указано в загрузчике класса должен лежать в CLASSPATH, в самом простом варианте в каталоге где лежат файлики `.class`

[Читаем мануал](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))!

Comment: спасибо за ответ, просто еще была картинка большого расширения и я пытался её вставить в JLabel )))
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(GridBagLayoutTest.class.getResource("help.jpg"));
вот так
JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(icon);
теперь все работает